# What is the correct way for quering a NSNumber in a NSArray within CoreData?

Tags: core-data, nsarray, nspredicate, nsnumber, nsfetchrequest

I have a Entity with a column of type ID named "responsibleUsers". In this column I store an Array containing NSNumbers.
I want to fetch all objects of this entity, that match my current User. Therefore i create following predicate:

```
    [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"%@ IN responsibleUsers",[NSNumber numberWithInteger: curUser.oID.integerValue] ]
```

whatever I try, my App crashes. Once with a EXC_BAD_ACESS, once with "unimplemented SQL generation for predicate nsnumber"

What is the correct way to query my entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query you are trying assumes that you have two entities: the entity you querying (let's call it `Group`) and another one, perhaps called `User`, which is set up as a to-many relationship from `Group` called `responsibleUsers`. You would then be able to use the predicate you suggest:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ IN responsibleUsers, aUser];
```

This would be the recommended use of Core Data object graphs.

In your setup, it seems you have an array of `NSNumber` set as a **property** rather than a relationship. Therefore you cannot use such a query. You simply have to retrieve the array and query the array.

```
BOOL containsResponsibleUser = NO;
for (NSNumber *n in aGroup.responsibleUsers) {
    if ([n isEqualTo:[NSNumber numberWithInteger: curUser.oID.integerValue]]) 
       containsResponsibleUser = YES;
}
```

If you are indeed querying something like a group of users, I would recommend the first approach. If you are querying some kind of user, I would suggest a `BOOL` property `responsible` as the most efficient solution.

Comment: Thanks - Yes, you are absolutely right.
Storing NSArray within CoreData-Transformable-Property is against the nature of Core Data. I changed my model and code towards the usual relationship-mode and everything works finde... thank you.